# How can I make a GSC change of address from a TLD to subdirectory?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, migration

I am moving from `https://www.exampleA.com/` to `https://www.exampleB.com/directory/`. This is because the old site is now a part of a larger company so we are moving it into its directory. For this reason I am not redirecting to the root.

The problem is now I cannot use GSC change of address tool.

All my redirects are in place and those are fine. Is there a workaround I can do with redirects so I can use the change of address tool? If not, what are the downsides to not using it? I'm guessing Google will not transfer authority, seo value, etc. to the new domain?

Answer (score 0):

The GSC site move feature is for domain change purposes, and not paths of those domains. There is absolutely no way around this part because your the site address, not the path of pages which makes sense why Google doesn't allow it.

So simply change the domain to the new domain without the new homepage path. On the old domain you simply redirect the old URLS to the new ones, this will pass the rankings and authority, while GSC will help by ensuring the content is indexed.

Comment: You told me "So simply change the domain to the new domain without the new homepage path." Does this mean redirecting from olddomain.com to newdomain.com? That is not a relevant redirect and instead olddomain.com to newdomain.com/path is a much better experience.

Is redirecting all my old urls enough to tell Google I have moved? What am I losing out on without actually doing a site move in GSC settings?

Comment: I think your missing the point... the site address tool is simply for telling Google you have a new domain, it's not for anything else... not paths, not sub domains, or protocols. Using the site address tool is useful for sites with high volume of URLS since it can use the current indexing from the old, to the new but you still need to use 301 redirects from old to new, and the root domain on the new domain should redirect also to the new path.